# How do I create URLs in Excel based on data in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Consider the following Excel sheet:

```
     A             B                       C
1 ASX:ANZ      ANZ:ASX       http://www.site.com/page?id=ANZ:ASX
2 DOW:1234     1234:DOW      http://www.site.com/page?id=1234:DOW
3 NASDAQ:EXP   EXP:NASDAQ    http://www.site.com/page?id=EXP:NASDAQ
```

I need a formula for the `B` and the `C` column. In the `B` column I need the values of the `A` column to be split on `:` and the two resulting parts to be reversed, see the three examples. In the `C` column, I need the result from `B` to be added to a (hardcopy) URL (`http://www.site.com/page?id=`) to form a link.

Who can help me out? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright. I don't normally spoon feed answers but here you go.

In B:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(":", A1, 1)+1, LEN(A1) - FIND(":",A1,1)) & ":"&MID(A1,1,FIND(":",A1,1)-1)
```

In C:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.site.com/page?id="&B1)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
=hyperlink("http://www.site.com/page?id="&B1) *english version *
```

Answer (score -1):

The loop looks something like his:

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim snumber As Variant
Dim TestCell As String
Dim lastcell As Integer

Sheets("data").Select


lastcell = Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For row = 1 To lastcell
    TestCell = "A" & row
    snumber = Range(TestCell).Value
    If snumber <> "" And snumber <> "0" Then
        Range(TestCell).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "url goes here", TextToDisplay:=snumber
    End If
Next row
```

Comment: I don't see how this is even close to what OP wants.